# Parseo XML con uso de RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

estoy haciendo una app que consume datos de un xml que proviene de internet, estos datos consumidos son mostrados en CardViews dentro de un RecyclerView para luego al presionar en la imagen del CardView se abra otra pantalla con los detalles (Imágen, titulo de noticia y contenido de la noticia), en el cardview sólo muestro imagen, fecha/hora, y el titulo.

Los detalles de la noticia son capturados de otro archivo XML y que la ruta se arma en función de un número único que viene en el primer XML. Lamentablemente no he logrado conseguir que me muestre los detalles de la noticia en un layout que simplemente tiene ImageView, TextView(título) y TextView(noticia completa).

Esta es la clase MyAdapter en donde hago el seteo.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Article> articles;


public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Article> articles) {
    this.c = c;
    this.articles = articles;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int 
position) 
  {
     final Article article=articles.get(position);
    System.out.println("MyAdater, position es: "+position);
     String title=article.getTitle();
    //String desc=article.getDescription();
    String dateFecha=article.getTsFecha();
    String dateHora=article.getTsHora();
    String imageUrl=article.getImageUrl();
    final String tsarticle=article.getTsArticle();

    holder.titleTxt.setText(title);
    holder.dateFechaTxt.setText(dateFecha);
    holder.dateHoraTxt.setText(dateHora);


    String baseUrl = "http://www.ejemplo.cl";
    String cadenaUrl = baseUrl+imageUrl;

   // Log.i("valor total cadena",": "+cadenaUrl);
    Picasso.with(c).load(cadenaUrl).into(holder.img);

    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(c, PictureDetailActivity.class);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

                Explode explode = new Explode();
                explode.setDuration(1000);
                //si estuvieramos en una actividad no sería necesario 
  agregar activity.getWindow, solo getWindow
                //activity.getWindow()

                //como personalizamos la duración de la transición(el objeto 
   Explode), debemos colocar el nombre de la clase instanciada,
                // .setExitTransition(explode);
                // de lo contrario solo sería .setExitTransition(new 
   Explode()); y toma los valores por defecto de Explode.

           //  c.getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
               // activity.startActivity(intent, ActivityOptionsCompat.
                 //       

makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,v,activity.getString
(R.string.transitonname_picture))
                 //       .toBundle());



              //  Log.i("el ts es "," :"+tsarticle.toString());
                intent.putExtra("article_object", article);
               c.startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                c.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
  }
      @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return articles.size();
    }

  }
```

Esta es la clase RSSParser, en donde hago el parseo del archivo XML (en este momento no voy a dejar la clase en donde hago la conexión HttpURLConnection)

```
public class RSSParserDetail implements Serializable{

    Context c;

private InputStream urlStream;
private XmlPullParserFactory factory;
private XmlPullParser parser;

private List<ArticleDetail> rssFeedList;
private ArticleDetail rssFeed;

private String urlString;
private String tagName;

private  String title;
private String link;
private String description;

public static final String ITEM = "artic_data";
public static final String CHANNEL = "public";
public static final String TITLE = "_txt_titular";
public static final String LINK = "fotofija_port_649x365";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "vtxt_cuerpo";


  public RSSParserDetail( String urlString ) {
      this.urlString=urlString;
}

 public static InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException 
 {

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;
 }

  public List<ArticleDetail> parse() {
    try {
        int count = 0;
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        parser = factory.newPullParser();
        urlStream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        parser.setInput(urlStream, null);
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        boolean done = false;
        rssFeed = new ArticleDetail();
        rssFeedList = new ArrayList<ArticleDetail>();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {
            tagName = parser.getName();

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                        rssFeed = new ArticleDetail();
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(TITLE)) {
                        title = parser.nextText().toString();
                        System.out.println("Muestrame el titulo, 
      RSSParserDetail: "+title);
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(LINK)) {
                        link = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(DESCRIPTION)) {
                        description = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals(CHANNEL)) {
                        done = true;
                    } else if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                        rssFeed=new ArticleDetail(title,link,description);
                        rssFeedList.add(rssFeed);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return rssFeedList;
   }

}
```

Al presionar en la imagen del CardView, esta me envía a través de un Intent PictureDetailActivity, y dado que el archivo a parsear es distinto (en tag y contenido) al anterior tuve que realizar otra clase llamada RSSParserDetail.

Esta es la clase PictureDetailActivity.

```
public class PictureDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
Serializable{

RSSParserDetail rssParserDetail;
private List<ArticleDetail> mRssFeedList;
Context c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_detail);
    setElement();
   // showToolbar("",true);

    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Fade());
    c = getApplicationContext();

 }
     public void setElement (){
      Article article = (Article) 
     getIntent().getSerializableExtra("article_object");

     //Armando Url para capturar archivo de articulo en servidor
    String tsArticle = article.getTsArticle();
    String baseUrl="https://www.cooperativa.cl/noticias/site/artic/";
    String titleDetail = article.getTitle();
    String dataTs = tsArticle.substring(0,8);
    String aammdd = dataTs;
    String directorioXml="/xml/";
    String finalUrl= tsArticle+".xml";
    String linkXml=baseUrl+aammdd+directorioXml+finalUrl;
    //***********************************************************
    String linkPaso="http://especiales2.cooperativa.cl/
    2017/pruebas/rvargas/prontus_art_view_xml.xml";
    System.out.println("estoy en PictureDetailActivity");

   new DoRssFeedTask().execute(linkPaso);
   }

   public class DoRssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, 
    List<ArticleDetail>> {
    ProgressDialog prog;
    String jsonStr = null;
    Handler innerHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prog = new ProgressDialog(PictureDetailActivity.this);
        prog.setMessage("Loading....");
        prog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ArticleDetail> doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (String urlVal : params) {
            rssParserDetail = new RSSParserDetail(urlVal);
        }
       // mRssFeedList = mNewsFeeder.parse();
        mRssFeedList=rssParserDetail.parse();
        return mRssFeedList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ArticleDetail> result) {
        prog.dismiss();
     // new MyAdapterDetail();
        Intent intent = new Intent(PictureDetailActivity.this, 
  MyAdapterDetail.class);
         startActivity(intent);

        System.out.println("PictureDetailActivity onPostExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}

public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton/*, View view*/){
    /*se crea el metodo showtoolbar para traer toolbar según maqueta de 
diseño*/
    /*este metodo no debe llevar view porque estamos en cotexto de 
 activity*/

    /*Estamos en contexto de Activity, es por eso que no debe de llevar el 
 código ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity())
    al llevar este código a un fragment si debe llevar ese codigo
     */

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingtoolbarlayout =  
  (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);/*aún no 
   funcional, sea crea para el proximo curso*/

   }

}
```

Y esta es la clase RSSParserDetail.

```
public class RSSParserDetail implements Serializable{

Context c;

private InputStream urlStream;
private XmlPullParserFactory factory;
private XmlPullParser parser;

private List<ArticleDetail> rssFeedList;
private ArticleDetail rssFeed;

private String urlString;
private String tagName;

String title;
String link;
String description;

public static final String ITEM = "artic_data";
public static final String CHANNEL = "public";
public static final String TITLE = "_txt_titular";
public static final String LINK = "fotofija_port_649x365";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "vtxt_cuerpo";


  public RSSParserDetail( String urlString ) {
      this.urlString=urlString;
}

public static InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;
}

public List<ArticleDetail> parse() {
    try {
        int count = 0;
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        parser = factory.newPullParser();
        urlStream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        parser.setInput(urlStream, null);
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        boolean done = false;
        rssFeed = new ArticleDetail();
        rssFeedList = new ArrayList<ArticleDetail>();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {
            tagName = parser.getName();

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                        rssFeed = new ArticleDetail();
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(TITLE)) {
                        title = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(LINK)) {
                        link = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }
                    if (tagName.equals(DESCRIPTION)) {
                        description = parser.nextText().toString();
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equals(CHANNEL)) {
                        done = true;
                    } else if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                        rssFeedList.add(rssFeed);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rssFeedList;
  }

}
```

Esta es la clase MyAdapterDetail, que es en donde envío los elementos para comenzar a setear.

```
public class MyAdapterDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    Serializable {
     //ArrayList<RSSParserDetail> articles;

     //ArticleDetail articles = new ArticleDetail();
    //ArrayList<ArticleDetail> articles;
    Context c;
   //ArticleDetail articles;
   MyViewHolderDetail myViewHolderDetail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // ArticleDetail article=articles.get(0);

  //articles= (ArrayList<ArticleDetail>) 
    getIntent().getSerializableExtra("objeto");
   // System.out.println("MyAdapterDetail tamaño de arreglo que llega es de: 
    "+articles.size());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_detail);
    showToolbar("",true);
    System.out.println("Estoy en el AdapterDetail");
    setElementDetail();
   }

    public void setElementDetail(){
    //System.out.println("MyAdapterDetail en setElemetDetail, el tamaño de 
     arreglo es: "+articles.size());

     ArticleDetail article = new ArticleDetail();
     //String imageUrl=article.getImageUrlDetail();
     String title=article.getTitleDetail();
    //String desc=article.getContDetail();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.cooperativa.cl";
   //String cadenaUrl = baseUrl+imageUrl;

   //Picasso.with(c).load(cadenaUrl).into(myViewHolderDetail.img);
  //myViewHolderDetail.titleTxtDetail.setText(title);
 //myViewHolderDetail.titleDetail.setText(desc);

    //System.out.println("Mi cadena URL es: "+cadenaUrl);
    System.out.println("Mi titulo es: "+title);
  //System.out.println("Mi Detalle es: "+desc);
 }

 public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton/*, View view*/){
    /*se crea el metodo showtoolbar para traer toolbar según maqueta de 
     diseño*/
    /*este metodo no debe llevar view porque estamos en cotexto de 
     activity*/

    /*Estamos en contexto de Activity, es por eso que no debe de llevar el 
       código ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity())
    al llevar este código a un fragment si debe llevar ese codigo
     */

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingtoolbarlayout =  
    (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);/*aún no 
    funcional, sea crea para el proximo curso*/
     }
   }



06-13 17:23:45.032 28631-28631/cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial 
                               I/System.out: Estoy en el AdapterDetail
06-13 17:23:45.032 28631-28631/cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial 
                               I/System.out: Mi titulo es: null
```

Traté de detallar lo más posible mi problema, quedo atento a cualquier comentario. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Muy detallada tu pregunta!, analizando el LogCat se puede determinar el problema, es el valor de la variable c , que no se inicializa con el contexto .

Comment: Gracias, ahora si no me presenta el erro, pero si tengo valores nulos, voy a actualizar mi pregunta agregando un código de otra clase.

Comment: Edité la clase RSSParserDetail

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre en la clase `PictureDetailActivity` :

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
```

La variable `c` que debiera tener el contexto, tiene valor `null` cuando intentas realizar `startActivity()` :

```
c.startActivity(intent);
```

puedes asignar el valor de c dentro de `onCreate()` de esta forma:

```
  c = this; //*** Asigna valor del contexto.
```

o de esta forma:

```
  c = getApplicationContext(); //*** Asigna valor del contexto.
```

**Es importante comentar también que si estas en una Activity, no necesitas el contexto para llamar `startActivity()`**, simplemente :

```
 startActivity(intent);
```

---

por ejemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_detail);
    setElement();
   // showToolbar("",true);

    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Fade());

    c = getApplicationContext(); //*** Asigna valor del contexto.

 }
```